# How to use Inherited Methods using Type Erasure?

Tags: java, inheritance, types, erasure

I'm trying to use type erasure in order to access the inherited methods of the general type.

I have a parent class, Space, and child classes, Scalar, Vector, Mapping, etc. I want an interface, Function, for which I can specify the domain and range among the various child classes of Space.

The class, Mapping, contains the interface, Function, and should be able to access it through the method, Of.

If the programmer wants to take the mapping of a double, i.e.,

```
Mapping map = new Mapping(...);
Scalar answer = map(0.0);
```

then I want the function, Of, to convert the double to a Scalar and then pass it on to the interface, Function.

```
public class Mapping<Domain extends Space, Range extends Space> extends Space{

    protected Function<Domain,Range> function;

    public Range of(Double point){
        return function.of(new Scalar(point)); //Error, the type <Domain,Range> is not applicable to type Scalar.
    }
}

public interface Function<Domain extends Space,Range extends Space>{
    public Range of(Domain point);
}

public class Scalar extends Space {
    protected double value=0.0;
    public Scalar(double in){
        value = in;
    }
```

Eclipse recommends casting Scalar to Domain, but since Domain extends Space, as does Scalar, shouldn't a Scalar be acceptable to pass to Function?

***Edit:***

I have constructors for each child class that take in Scalar as an argument, e.g., `Public Vector(Scalar x){...}`. I want `Mapping` to take in a double, convert it to a `Scalar`, and then if the `Domain` of the function is, for example, a Vector, then I would like the `Vector(Scalar x)` constructor called.

Ideally, I would just have a parent constructor of a double:

```
public Range of(Double point){
    return function.of(new Domain(point));
}
```

But I can't implement a generic type. This is the problem I'm trying to work around. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: "but since Domain extends Space, as does Scalar, shouldn't a Scalar be acceptable to pass to Function?" - no, `Domain` might not be `Scalar`. It's *some* type that extends `Space`, but that doesn't mean it's definitely `Scalar`. If I provide a `Function<SomeOtherSpace, SomeRange>` where `SomeOtherSpace` is a class that extends `Space` but isn't `Scalar`, what would you expect that to do with a `Scalar` value?

Comment: @JonSkeet I see your point. I have constructors for the other child classes that take a Scalar as an argument, e.g., `Public Vector(Scalar x)`, etc. If I cast `Scalar` to `(Domain)` then will `Mapping` call the constructor for those other classes when passed? I.e., if I have a `Mapping<Vector,Scalar> map`, and I call `map.of(0.0)`, will the cast, `(Domain) Scalar`, call the constructor `Vector(Scalar)`? Or do I need to implement a constructor `Space(Scalar x)` in the parent class?

Comment: No, because Java doesn't "know" the actual type of `Domain` at execution time. You'd need to also pass in a `Function<Double, Domain>`.

Answer (score 0):

With the current definition of `Function` interface, the method `of` can only take in an object of type `Scalar`. The `Mapping` class won't compile because inheritance only work in one direction. `Scalar` inherits from `Space`, but the `Space` doesn't inherit from `Scalar`. So you can't expect the `Mapping` class to be able to pass a `Space` object to the method in `Function`.

The design of your classes need some refactoring, but it's not clear what you want to achieve, because the design is conflicting with itself.

For example, the `Function` interface only deals with `Scalar` values. Meanwhile, the `Mapping` class is expected to take in any domain of `Space` type (`Vector`, `Scalar`, etc..). If you want your `Mapping` class to accept any `Space` type, then you can't limit its `Function` to only accept `Scalar`.

Comment: Oops! That was a transcription error. It should be `Class Function<Domain extends Space, Range extends Space>`.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to implement here, so it's not easy to tell you which approach would be best. Please, provide the high level user story without talking about classes and implementation details. For example, I want to map a vector to a scalar...